# Android client force-closing

Tags: android, tcp

im new to android and was wondering if someone can help me with this this is the code i have.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try
      {
      Socket TestSocket = new Socket("96.29.64.93",2215);
      OutputStream writer = TestSocket.getOutputStream();
      writer.write(new byte[]{1});
      writer.flush();

      InputStream reader = TestSocket.getInputStream();
      byte array[] = new byte[1];
      int i = reader.read(array);
      }catch(IOException ex)
        {
        Log.e("TcpTest","Error",ex);
        }
     }
   }
```

EDIT:
internet permissions set in manifest app force closes here is logcat.
http://i43.tinypic.com/25tc1o7.png

if i take off internet permissions it doesn't force close.

And thanks to all that posted answers here so far.

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission added to `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Add the logcat. Without it we can not help.

Comment: yes i added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: sorry like i said im new to android how to get logcat?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to make a connection on the UI thread and ICS is crashing your app (as it should, since attempting to connect to a web server on the UI thread is almost certainly a guarantee that your app will not function correctly). Ensure that you are making the connection using an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`.

---

#### Edit:

You asked for some clarification, so here it goes. From an Android [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) on the Developer's site:

> When an application is launched, the system creates a thread called
>   "main" for the application. The main thread, also called the UI
>   thread, is very important because it is in charge of dispatching the
>   events to the appropriate widgets, including drawing events. It is
>   also the thread where your application interacts with running
>   components of the Android UI toolkit.
>
> For instance, if you touch the a button on screen, the UI thread
>   dispatches the touch event to the widget, which in turn sets its
>   pressed state and posts an invalidate request to the event queue. The
>   UI thread dequeues the request and notifies the widget to redraw
>   itself.
>
> This single-thread model can yield poor performance unless your
>   application is implemented properly. Specifically, if everything is
>   happening in a single thread, performing long operations such as
>   network access or database queries on the UI thread will block the
>   whole user interface. No event can be dispatched, including drawing
>   events, while the long operation is underway. From the user's
>   perspective, the application appears hung. Even worse, if the UI
>   thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds
>   currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not
>   responding" (ANR) dialog.

This applies to your situation, as attempting to establish a socket connection between a client and a server will *block* the UI Thread--the user will not be able to interact with the screen at all until the connection is made (and this won't get you too many good reviews in the Android Market :P). Therefore, it is very important to perform potentially expensive/long-term operations on a separate Thread. The easiest way to do this is to use an `AsyncTask`, which are very easy to implement and essentially abstract the entire idea of `Thread`s so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: This is assuming you are writing your application for ICS, of course. If not, you should still ensure that you are creating new `Socket`s on a separate `Thread` only.

Comment: I just looked at your updated post... the problem was that the `new Socket()` instruction was blocking the UI thread from drawing the screen layout... a combination of both our answers :). Make sure you fix this problem, it is very important!!

Comment: could you explain a little better im new to android and java i use c++

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4356919/844882) for some sample code.

Comment: I just updated my answer... hope that clarifies things for you. I'm not familiar with C++ threading, so I can't be sure :).

Comment: allright i look into threading thank for the tip.just to make sure my program can force close cause im hanging up the ui?

Comment: Yup. If the UI hangs for ~5 seconds the system will automatically force close your app.

Answer (score 0):

What if you move the `setContentView` above the `try` statement?

Comment: thanks i did a you suggested and it no longer force closes but i found in logat it says tcptest error(that how i got it programmed). Log.e("TcpTest","Error");
is there a way to change it to get more descriptive error?