# Android read/write in same socket from ServerSocket

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream, serversocket, outputstream

I have an android app which will create a **ServerSocket** and accept a socket.
I want it can communicate(read/write) with remote device.

My sample code like following:

```
mListenSocket = new ServerSocket();
mListenSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
mListenSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(DOCK_PORT));
mSocket = mListenSocket.accept();

Thread {
    loop {
    outputStream = mSyncSocket.getOutputStream();
    inputStream = mSyncSocket.getInputStream();
    ...
    inputStream.read(data)
    outputStream.write(data);
    ...
    }
}
```

It can read right inputStream data from client, but the second time read() always return -1 after I write data in outputStream firt time .

I have no idea about this issue.
Somebody can give me some tips? Thanks a lot.

======================================================================

I think I need to express my problem more clearly.

There are two devices(A, B), and their workflow as follows:

Type 1 task:
1. A sends command to B
2. B receives command and reply message to A
3. A receives message, Done.

Type 2 task:
1. A sends command to B, Done.

Above tasks are asynchronized.

My old method was that create a ServerSocket on A and B device respectively to handle A->B and B->A communication.
**I think maybe one socket can resolve above task, but one socket will encounter read -1 issue.**
Someone can give me more advices? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take the first two statements of the loop out of the loop. Put them before the loop. You should initiate those variables only once.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.'loop' is something like 'while', 'for' ...etc
sample code omitted too much.
I did initiate those variables before loop.

Answer (score 0):

`read()` returns -1 because the peer has closed the connection. You should do likewise, and stop reading, and stop handling the connection completely. It's finished.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I'm really appreciate your response.

Answer (score -1):

I use something like this:

```
final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());   
final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

// Send the login data.
final JSONObject login = new JSONObject();

// Send the login message.
dos.write((login.toString() + "\r\n").getBytes());

// Wait until we receive something from the server.
String receivedMessage;
while ((receivedMessage = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received data: " + receivedMessage);
    processMessagesFromServer(dos, receivedMessage);
}
```

I use a normal socket instead of `ServerSocket`.
Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247141/android-how-to-run-a-socket-in-a-long-lives-background-thread) for more information.

Comment: Zero evidence here that the client is sending lines. The mixture of `DataOutputStream` and `BufferedInputStream`is bizarre.

Comment: We always use the `\r\n` separator .. so for us it is working properly. Do you have better idea instead of the mixture of `DataOutputStream` and `BufferedInputStream`? Please share it with us.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
I'm really appreciate your response.